# How do I compute in R a rm MANOVA with three types of SEN as a within factor and two dimensions as dependent measures?

Tags: r, manova

I want to compute a repeated measures MANOVA with type of special educational needs for three groups as a within subject factor and two dimensions called warmth and competence as dependent measures in order to see whether the warmth and competence rating of the three groups differ.
My data consists of each participants' rating of warmth and competence for each group w1, w2, w3 and c1, c2 and c3.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.